# kafka consumer on partitioned topic does not start if another running

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am trying to implement a multiple consumer - single producer setup with kafka. I created a topic with 3 partitions as follows:

```
./kafka-create-topic.sh --topic stream.main.out --zookeeper 
localhost:2181 --partition 3
```

the producer is setup as follows:

```
     props = new Properties();
     props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
     props.put("broker.list","xxx.xxx.x:9092,.....");
     props.put("request.required.acks", "1");
     props.put("topic.metadata.refresh.interval.ms", "1");
     props.put("partitioner.class", "kafka.producer.DefaultPartitioner");
    //props.put("enable.auto.cimmit","true");
    //props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms","10");
```

Now if I fire up the first consumer it runs fine; starting the second consumer is where the problem lies. It starts up but seems to be waiting for messages and nothing happens for more than 10 minutes. Why is this happening?
I tried doing this initially without multiple partitions but then each consumer seemed to get the same message even with the same group ID.

```
        props = new Properties();
        props.put("metadata.broker.list", "192.xxxx:9092,....");
        props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
        props.put("broker.list","192.1xxx:9092,192....");
        props.put("request.required.acks", "1");
        ConsumerConnector consumer = 
        kafka.consumer.Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector(
            createConsumerConfig(zooKeeper, groupId));

    Map<String, Integer> topicCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    topicCountMap.put(topic, new Integer(1));
    Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>> consumerMap = consumer.createMessageStreams(topicCountMap);
    List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>> streams = consumerMap.get(topic);

    for ( KafkaStream stream : streams) {
         ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> it = stream.iterator();
         while (it.hasNext())
```

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, this issue has to do with `group.id` ([Group ID](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Group+Example)). If you are using the same `group.id` for both consumers then they will read different set of partitions i.e. different set of messages.

If you'd like to consume all messages from both consumers, then  you must define a **different** `group.id` for each distinct consumer.

According to the official [Kafka documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#intro_consumers):

> Consumers label themselves with a consumer group name, and each record
>   published to a topic is delivered to one consumer instance within each
>   subscribing consumer group. Consumer instances can be in separate
>   processes or on separate machines.
>
> If all the consumer instances have the same consumer group, then the
>   records will effectively be load balanced over the consumer instances.
>
> If all the consumer instances have different consumer groups, then
>   each record will be broadcast to all the consumer processes.

If you use different `group.id` for each consumer and you are still unable to read the messages from both sides you can try to run the console consumers and make sure that there is nothing wrong with the consumer class you've created.

```
kafka-console-consumer --broker-list 192.1xxx:9092,192.... --topic topic_name --from-beginning
```

Comment: I will try the console consumers as I am using the same group ID

Comment: As I mentioned you should use a **different** group ID

Comment: I dont want each consumer to get the same message. Basically want it like a queue with one message per consumer or a single copy to a consumer. Want to increase processing speed but avoid duplicates